# function to do helm-do-ag for a specific project

Tags: helm

I want to wrap the helm-do-ag in another function to search in a specific dir. The following is the description of helm-do-ag.

```
helm-do-ag is an interactive Lisp closure in `helm-ag.el'.
(helm-do-ag &optional BASEDIR TARGETS)
```

I have the following function (minimal working example):

```
(defun helm-do-ag-project ()
  "ag the string in the given project"
(interactive)
(let ((helm-ag-command-option (concat helm-ag-command-option " -G v$ -f --verilog ")))
 (helm-do-ag (concat "d:/Projects/ProjectName/workarea/module_name/hdl/rtl")))
)
```

But, the results it returns are:

```
rtl/filename.v: ...text....
rtl/mod1/filename1.v ....text....
```

The problem is the result also has the "rtl"(**rtl** is the dir provided as part of the BASEDIR. Hence I am not able to open the file using persistent action. Helm tries to look for

d:/Projects/ProjectName/workarea/module_name/hdl/rtl/**rtl**/filename.v

and *helm* is unable to open the file, since path is not correct.

Comment: (defun helm-do-ag-project ()
      "Grep the string in the given project"
        (interactive)
        (let ((rootdir (concat "d:/Projects/ProjectName/workarea/module_name/hdl/rtl/")))
               (let ((helm-ag-command-option (concat helm-ag-command-option " -G v$ -f --verilog ")))
            (helm-do-ag rootdir))))

Comment: The above code worked. The main difference was - the dir name should have a "/" at the end. The following will not work. "d:/Projects/ProjectName/workarea/module_name/hdl/rtl" But this will work: "d:/Projects/ProjectName/workarea/module_name/hdl/rtl/"        - note the "/" at after "rtl"

Comment: This question can be closed.